BeDrive localhost Error over Lan connection
I’ve set up BeDrive on my local host, but when attempting to access it from another computer on the same LAN network, I encounter a ‘404 Not Found’ error. I’ve attached a screenshot of the error for referenceenter image description here
I attempted to configure all inbound settings and included listening with the computer's IP address, but I'm still encountering the same error."
